# Hook in with ebean transaction (before commit?) for dealing with external (google) resources?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have my Play Framework (2.3.1) controllers annotated with @play.db.ebean.Transactional, and am sometimes creating google calendar resources in the middle of the transaction.  I'd like some way to hook in with the transaction (like beforeCommit() in EJB/JPA) so I can handle my google transaction there instead.

Is there any way to do this in Play with Ebean?

The Play documentation is very sparse on this.  I've tried tagging controller methods with @PrePersist and @PostPersist, but the methods don't seem to get called.

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: I have similar issues with PrePersist, so I extended play.db.ebean.Model to create an AbstractModel class.  This defines some empty methods like beforeSave(), beforeUpdate(), etc, and overrides the existing save, update, etc methods to invoke those methods before calling the super method.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  That's a useful idea.  I really ideally want to hook in at the controller and/or transaction level (not the model), but perhaps the model will have to do.
I assume you call these methods right at the start of the save() method, before calling super, and they can throw an exception if they want to kill the transaction?

Comment: Exactly - it's a bit of a hack, but TBH I've seen some very odd behaviour coming from EBean.  At some point in the near future, I'll be completely removing it from my current project and replacing it with something more predictable and JPA compliant.

Comment: Hmm, OK, thanks for that.  Would love to have a chat if you are up for it about the strange behaviour, as I'm about to launch a big project with it.  Seems to be working fine for me so far..

Comment: Head over to my github page - you can find contact details there.